# Ajax Control Toolkit Disabled Error in ToolBox with VS2022

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I worked with Ajax Control Toolkit in my installed branch. But when I opened the new branch the toolkit did not appear in toolbox. When I tried to add; it said it's already available. I erased dll from bin file and reset toolbox then I could install but this time it is disabled mode. I cannot enable toolkit although I passed old branch.

Comment: Toolbox is disabled but from source I could add and run.

Comment: You should be able to open up the mange nuget packages area, and click on the update packages button. You could I suppose install the aj toolkit with nuget, but either way,  you need to install that package, or hit the "update packages" button if you just cloned the project from github....